# Does fsck keep existing files?

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, fsck

This is a rather dumb question but my googling didn't give me any direct anwser. So I have a computer which ubuntu (12.04) filesystem has gone corrupted. Now I want to try to repair it with `fsck` from a live usb but since there are alot of important files (mainly pictures) I want my files not to get deleted. So I'd like to know that does `fsck` keeps my files when I start the repair process?

Comment: Why would you think checking/repairing a filesystem would delete your files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fsck does not touch your files. It is basically a front-end program that does all kinds of **filesystem** checks (ie. it checks the integrity of the journaling system).

If you run it interactively it will report on what it did. The checks it runs are:

```
** Phase 1 - Check Blocks and Sizes
** Phase 2 - Check Pathnames
** Phase 3 - Check Connectivity
** Phase 4 - Check Reference Counts
** Phase 5 - Check Cyl groups
```

and below this it will show a summary of

- Number of inodes in use
- Number of fragments in use
- Number of unused fragments
- Number of unused non-block fragments
- Number of unused full blocks
- Percentage of fragmentation, where: free fragments x 100 / total fragments in the file system

Besides checking inodes and blocks fsck also checks for incorrect `.` and `..` entries and incorrect directories.

More reading material (links from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) on fsck):

- [adminchoice.com](http://www.adminschoice.com/repairing-unix-file-system-fsck/)
- [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/6j6q7uf0e/index.html)
- [lwn.net](http://lwn.net/Articles/248180/)

Comment: short * simple .

Comment: Thank-you for explaining me this in detail. I got my filesystem fixed and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct track, running fsck either from liveCD or from rescue mode. Mainly you file system (esp `/` partition) should be umounted before running `fsck` therefore you would need to use recovery mode or use liveCD.

`fsck.{ext2/3/4,btrfs,xfs}` etc does a lot of work in phases, to fix both the metadata and data corruption in your FS also identifying and bad sectors (which will only be marked not to use, and remains unfixed) on the underlying storage. It actually depends on the underlying file system as every file system (ext2/3/4,btrfs,xfs) has a unique design and have its own version of fsck, if you like to understand the exact details its best to go through the source code.

NOTE: its important to make multiple runs, if your previous run **had errors** and some were **fixed**, this is because the metadata is fixed sequentially. Keep running until the previous run had no errors.